# Ethernet Switch and QoS Support

Tags: ethernet, phy

I'm going through the Ethernet Switch IC - [Link](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/KSZ9893#:%7E:text=The%20KSZ9893%20is%20a%20fully,as%20RGMII%2C%20MII%20or%20RMII.)

In the first page, under highlights section, it is mentioned as switch is QoS support.

When I tried to research on what QoS means on this [Link](https://cyberhoot.com/cybrary/quality-of-service-qos/), I found the below image:

[image]

But as I recall, Ethernet protocol was a baseband interface protocol (meaning that either video or audio will be taking up the entire bandwidth). But the above image suggests that Ethernet might be a broadband protocol(Video, audio and others are sharing the bandwidth).

What is this conflict about? Or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: Ethernet does not know or care what the data is, as it is just packets of data. And how does even being baseband or broadband relate to this question? How Ethernet works protocol-wise is not an electronics question, it is a network engineering question.

Comment: QoS is a method of assigning priorities to certain packet types in order to utilise the available data bandwidth more effectively. Your link tells you this in the first paragraph!

Comment: Yes, but I have read that the Ethernet is a baseband type of communication. But QoS implies the protocol will behave as broadband

Comment: @Justme, yes. But I've read that Ethernet is a baseband transmission type of communication. Since, its baseband, we cannot allot portion of the bandwidths like the above image in the question, right? The above image represents a broadband type of communication. But clearly, Ethernet is not broadband. So, could you help to clarify Ethernet being baseband but still providing QoS support (QoS exhibits broadband communication, right)?

Comment: But QoS implies a broadband type of communication. So, how can Ethernet switch offer QoS ?

Comment: QoS does not imply broadband so you just have incorrect assumptions. The datasheet says the chip implements 802.1p protocol. Please try doing some researching, like read Wikipedia article on QoS.

Comment: Don't focus on the broadband/baseband notion, it does not mean what you think it means. And, more importantly don't try to correlate this with QoS. Both concepts are orthogonal. QoS gives you the ability to priorize some packets, or guarantee some bandwith for certain usages (video / real-time / ...). Broadband/baseband is just a way to qualify the physical layer: broadband means that multiple bits are transmitted at the same time, but it typically bears no relationship with the usage of these bits (especially in an IP application).

Comment: Can you please write an answer explaining in a bit more detail @dim ?

Comment: @Newbie I'm sorry. Doing it would probably take me like 1 hour to formulate things correctly and do the research to accurately describe details. I have become way too lazy for this, unfortunately. But if you put aside your assumptions and look for the defintions of these terms, I'm sure you'll sort it out. You need to understand that the broadband/baseband concepts belong to the physical layer of the OSI stack, whereas QoS typically occurs at the network layer (layer 3). So there is no correlation, and QoS could be applied over whatever type of physical media.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QoS (Quality of Service) broadly refers to systems which allocate the available data rate among different data streams in some way other than the default. The picture does not represent different frequency bands; it represents fractions of the available data rate.

Without QoS packets are switched on something like a first-come-first-serve basis. With QoS you can (in principle) reserve 30% for video streaming, 20% for gaming services, and leave the rest for anything else. Video streaming gets a certain number of time slots where a video streaming packet will be sent if there is one.

Typically it doesn't actually reserve specific time slots, but rather gives priority to video streaming packets whenever they arrive, and also limits the fraction of video streaming packets to 30%. The effect is similar.

Note that in practice, identifying which packets are "video streaming packets" is quite difficult.

Comment: Could you please provide this answer related to Ethernet being baseband but having QoS

Comment: @Newbie why does baseband have anything to do with it?

Comment: When I checked the Wikipedia for Ethernet, we can see that the 10BASE-T, 100BASE-TX and all , the BASE stands for baseband right?

Comment: @Newbie yes? what does that have to do with prioritizing certain packets?

Comment: But QoS implies a broadband type of communication. So, how can Ethernet switch offer QoS

Comment: @Newbie no it doesn't

Comment: @Newbie Oh. The picture says "bandwidth" but computer people (as opposed to electronics people) often use "bandwidth" incorrectly to mean "data rate"

Comment: @user253751 Bandwidth means a lot of different things in different contexts and areas of science such as linear algebra, statistics, graph theory, etc, so you can't really say who is right or wrong about what bandwidth means, because it can mean a lot of things.

Comment: @Justme , can you please write an answer that will help to clarify the misunderstanding of mine please